# Find duplicate files in a directory using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, file, directory, duplicates

I'm currently writing a program that mass downloads images from various sources with given parameters from the user.

My issue is that I don't want duplicates to happen.
I should point out that I'm dealing with mass downloads of 100 max at a time (not so massive), and that each file has a different name, so simply searching by file name wouldn't work, I need to check hashes.

Anyways, here's what I've already found:

```
Directory.GetFiles(FullPath)
    .Select(f => new
        {
            FileName = f,
            FileHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(new FileStream(f, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
        })
    .GroupBy(f => f.FileHash)
    .Select(g => new { FileHash = g.Key, Files = g.Select(z => z.FileName).ToList() })
    .SelectMany(f => f.Files.Skip(1))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(File.Delete);
```

My issue is that on the "File.Delete" line, I get the oh so famous error that the file is already in use by another process. I think this is because the code above lacks a way to close the FileStream it's using to get the FileHash before Deleting the file, but I don't know how to resolve that, any ideas ?

I should also point out I've tried other solutions, like this one (without linq): https://www.bhalash.com/archives/13544802709
Replacing the print function with a delete one, no errors but doesn't work.

**Thanks in advance**, I stay available for any additional information required! :)

*Akitake*

Comment: Ah the wonders of one liner do it all ....

Comment: For anyone who stumbles on this old question, in addition to the excellent answers below, I'd like to add that the code above has some unnecessary inefficiencies. The `ToList` calls will add a lot unnecessary overhead, and the second definition of `FileHash` is completely unnecessary as it's never used later. So the lines after `GroupBy` can be replaced with a much simpler `.Select(g => g.Select(z => z.FileName)).SelectMany(f => f.Skip(1))`, and the second `ToList` call can be eliminated by putting the entire statement in a foreach loop and calling `File.Delete` inside the body of the foreach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to dispose the `FileStream`, so the file is still open until the GC collects the object.

You can replace the `Select` clause with:

```
.Select(f => {
    using (var fs = new FileStream(f, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        return new
        {
            FileName = f,
            FileHash = BitConverter.ToString(SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(fs))
        });
    }
})
```

Do **NOT** use `Encoding.UTF8` to encode arbitrary bytes (which a hash is), as the result could be an invalid UTF8 sequence. Use `BitConverter.ToString` if you must, or better yet: find a different way which does not involve strings.

For instance, you could write:

```
.Select(f => {
    // Same as above, but with:
    // FileHash = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(fs)
})
.GroupBy(f => f.FileHash, StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer)
```

---

You may use a better approach though: you may group the files by size first, and calculate the hash *only* if there are multiple files with the same size. That should perform better when there are not many duplicates.

Comment: Problem is: it will bail out as soon as it hits an error such as if any file is being used by another process.

Comment: @CarneyCode indeed, you have to decide what to do. I guess letting the exception be thrown *is* the correct default approach here, but if you just want to ignore this error, put the code in the lambda in a `try { ... } catch (IOException) { ... }` block.

Comment: StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer doesn't work on .NetCore

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem with disposing the file stream cleanly, you could split out the calculation of the file's hash into a method like this:

```
static string GetHash(string path)
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(fileStream));
    }
}
```

and consume it like this:

```
Directory.GetFiles(FullPath)
.Select(
f => new
{
    FileName = f,
    FileHash = GetHash(f)
})
.GroupBy(f => f.FileHash)
.Select(g => new { FileHash = g.Key, Files = g.Select(z => z.FileName).ToList() })
.SelectMany(f => f.Files.Skip(1))
.ToList()
.ForEach(File.Delete);
```

Comment: Your solution most likely works, I'll keep that solution in mind in the future, could be useful. Though @lucas-trzesniewski solution looks cleaner to me :)

Comment: Yeah, clean code is extremely subjective. Personally, I like removing logic out of huge LINQ statements to reduce the size and make them more expressive.

Comment: Problem is: it will bail out as soon as it hits an error such as if any file is being used by another process.