# Return only duplicate files from specified directory

Tags: c#, file, directory, duplicates

I am trying to return a list of all duplicate files within a directory. I have managed to return all file names from within the directory and subdirectories. I think I have code that allows duplicatae files to be returned but I want to return a list of all duplicate files and their paths to the console. I have created a FileDetail class which contains the folder, filename and filesize.
Would I need to create another class for duplicate files?
What would be the best way to return the list of all duplicate files found?

Relatively new to C# and using this task as a learning experience on ways to work with directories

```
private static void ListAllDuplicateFiles()
{

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(rootPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    List<string> duplicates = new List<string>();
    List<FileDetail> fileDetails = new List<FileDetail>();
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        FileDetail fileDetail = new FileDetail(fileInfo);
        fileDetails.Add(fileDetail);

        if (fileDetails.Select(f => f.Filename).Contains(file))
        {
            duplicates.Add(file);
        }
    }

    foreach (string duplicate in duplicates)
    {
        List<FileDetail> duplicateFileDetails = fileDetails.Where(f => f.Filename == duplicate).ToList();
    }

    foreach (FileDetail fileDetail in fileDetails)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fileDetail.Filename);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find duplicate files in a directory using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813048/find-duplicate-files-in-a-directory-using-linq)

Comment: It sadly does not really answer the question as I am able to gather the duplicates here but not sure how to give them their own class and return them as a list to console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're pretty close. But maybe you can achieve things a little easier.
So you're asking two questions.

First question: do i need to create a new class for duplicate files? In all fairness, it seems that even the first class is a little redundant as the class you're using: `System.IO.FileInfo` has all the properties you're interested in (or so it seems anyway). So, no i don't think you do. You can think of classes more in a way of structuring your data and possible determining behavior. If you don't need specific behavior nor need to add data to an already existing available class, might as well use it. :-)

The second question: What would be the best way to return the list of all duplicate files found? I guess the easiest way to do what you're doing, but  I'd change the datatype of 'duplicates' from `List<string>` to `List<FileInfo>` and put 'm in there when you find them.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(rootPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var fileInfos = new List<FileInfo>();
foreach(var item in files)
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(item);
    var doppelganger = fileInfos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == fileInfo.Name);
    if (doppelganger != null && duplicates.All(x => x.FullName != doppelganger.FullName))                
        duplicates.Add(doppelganger);
            
    if(doppelganger != null)
        duplicates.Add(fileInfo);
            
    fileInfos.Add(fileInfo);
}
```

So, what i'm doing is re-using the FileInfo class in System.IO and putting them in the list where ever necessary. Just to clarify on the 'doppelganger', if you want all doubles, that would include the one you're comparing to, right? That's why i'm also adding that one. Maybe this could be done more elegantly, but hey, there ya go.

Hope this helps! Happy coding